# How to display two functions next to each other in C++?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

The output of my code shows `function1()` above `function2()`. Is there a way to code so that the output would show `function1()` next to (as in side by side) `function2()`?

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function1()
{   
    int i;
    int array[5] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

    cout << "   -1-2-3-4-5-" << endl;
    cout << "   |";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << array[i] << "|";
        cout << endl;
}

void function2()
{   
    int i;
    char array[5] = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'};

    cout << "   -1-2-3-4-5-" << endl;
    cout << "   |";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << array[i] << "|";
        cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

   function1();
   function2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: dont use `endl` in `cout` of `function1()`

Comment: uhm, i guessed he wanted an output like 5<<A<<endl<<5<<A<<endl and so on. Alternating in each line between the functions. Or did i get you wrong, John?

Comment: @Anedar exactly. Both functions' first, second, and so on lines would be next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but not completely untricky.

The trick I used here is to pass the *output stream* to the function rather than have the function print to `std::cout` directly. This allows me to pass a [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to the function which prints to that instead. The [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) captures the output for later where I have a function to print both outputs one line at a time, next to each other:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// output to a generic output stream
// rather than hard-coding std::cout
void function1(std::ostream& os)
{
    int i;
    int array[5] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

    os << "   -1-2-3-4-5-" << '\n';
    os << "   |";
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        os << array[i] << "|";
    os << '\n';
}

void function2(std::ostream& os)
{
    int i;
    char array[5] = { 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A' };

    os << "   -1-2-3-4-5-" << '\n';
    os << "   |";
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        os << array[i] << "|";
    os << '\n';
}

// read each input stream line by line, printing them side by side
void side_by_side(std::istream& is1, std::istream& is2, std::size_t width)
{
    std::string line1;
    std::string line2;

    while(std::getline(is1, line1))
    {
        std::string pad;

        // ensure we add enough padding to make the distance
        // the same regardless of line length
        if(line1.size() < width)
            pad = std::string(width - line1.size(), ' ');

        // get same line from second stream
        std::getline(is2, line2);

        // print them size by the side the correct distance (pad)
        std::cout << line1 << pad << line2 << '\n';
    }

    // in case second stream has more line than the first
    while(std::getline(is2, line2))
    {
        auto pad = std::string(width, ' ');
        std::cout << pad << line2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // some stream objects to store the outputs
    std::stringstream ss1;
    std::stringstream ss2;

    // capture output in stream objects
    function1(ss1);
    function2(ss2);

    // print captured output side by side
    side_by_side(ss1, ss2, 30);
}
```

**Output:**

```
   -1-2-3-4-5-                   -1-2-3-4-5-
   |5|5|5|5|5|                   |A|A|A|A|A|
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

You call `function1()` first and afterwards call `function2()`, so they are executed one after another.

What you could do however is, let those functions only return the data as arrays or vectors and handle the output afterwards, once you have both results collected.

Another option would be to make the functions always only handle one iteration (you might want to use `static int i` or similar for this) and then loop outside of the function call.